# Inheritance for beginners

Tags: java, inheritance

I just started to learn java, so now i read about such possibility as inheritance, so try to create class that must create object - box. And using inheritance implement new properties to created object.
I try to put each class in separate file, so after creating class, try to use it in

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

So class Inheritance:

```
 public class Inheritance {
double width;
double height;
double depth;
Inheritance (Inheritance object){
    width = object.width;
    height = object.height;
    depth = object.depth;
}
Inheritance ( double w, double h, double d){
    width = w;
    height = h;
    depth = d;
}
Inheritance (){
    width = -1;
    height = -1;
    depth = -1;
}
Inheritance (double len){
    width=height=depth=len;
}
double volumeBox (){
    return width*height*depth;
}
class BoxWeight extends Inheritance {
    double weight;
    BoxWeight (double w, double h, double d, double m){
        super(w,h,d);
        weight = m;
    }
}
```

But, when i try to use BoxWeight in main class, during using i got an error

```
public class MainModule {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = new Inheritance.BoxWeight(9, 9, 9, 9);
....
```

Error - No enclosing instance of type Inheritance is accessible.
Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = new Inheritance().new BoxWeight(9, 9, 9, 9);

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan that's a possible solution. It would be great to post an answer explaining **why** that code works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, `BoxWeight` requires an instance of `Inheritance` to work (just like accessing a non-static variable or function requires an instance, so accessing a non-static inner class also does). If you change it to `static` it would work, but this isn't required.

`BoxWeight` doesn't need to be inside the `Inheritance` class.

Instead, remove `BoxWeight` out of the `Inheritance` class.

And change `Inheritance.BoxWeight` to `BoxWeight`.

**EDIT:** Just for completeness, you could also make it:

```
Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = new Inheritance().new BoxWeight(...);
```

`Inheritance.BoxWeight` is just the type, so the above does not apply. But to create an instance of `BoxWeight`, you need an `Inheritance` object, which you create with `new Inheritance()`.

Comment: Try to take out class BoxWeight - as you reccommended - now it ok

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
class BoxWeight extends Inheritance
```

to

```
static class BoxWeight extends Inheritance
```

This should allow your code to compile. However, in addition to using the inheritance feature of java, you're also using an inner class, which isn't really necessary in this case and is likely confusing things for you. If you pull `BoxWeight` out into its own file, and reference it without the `Inheritance.` prefix, I think you'll find things to be easier to understand.

Comment: Moving the `BoxWeight` class outside the `Inheritance` class definition will be better

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Agreed. I was still typing something to that effect as your comment came in...

Comment: do like 'static class BoxWeight1 extends Inheritance' and now its ok

Comment: @Bki yes but you're using a `static class`, that should be a new concept to learn for you (since you're a beginner), it's not hard to understand but the best solution (for now) should be moving your `BoxWeight` class outside the `Inheritance` class definition.

Comment: Move it out, remove 'static' in one file and 'Inheritance.' in another - now its ok too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your classes nested and not static (I don't see a good reason for it), you can also use:

```
Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = new Inheritance().new BoxWeight(9, 9, 9, 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = new Inheritance().new BoxWeight(9, 9, 9, 9);
```

You are here using both principles inheritance and inner class. Suppose that your class `BoxWeight` doesn't extend `Inheritance class`. Your inner class has access of the outer class some properties and methods which are object instance level attributes. So You should create `new Inheritance()` then by using this instance create an instance of `BoxWeight`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that this is an entirely arbitrary homework problem with crazy names, that extending a class inside the abstract class is an odd situation and that it makes no sense for a `BoxWeight` to be inside an `Inheritance`:

```
   ...
   Inheritance i = new Inheritance(0, 0, 0, 0);
   Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = i.new BoxWeight(9, 9, 9, 9);
   ...
```

`i` is the 'enclosing object'.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is in this line

```
Inheritance.BoxWeight mybox1 = new Inheritance.BoxWeight(9, 9, 9, 9);
```

use

```
BoxWeight mybox1 = new BoxWeight(9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0);
```

Comment: try - get new error - 'BoxWeight cannot be resolved to a type' Also usefull add 'static' to class BoxWeight, as recommended by Asaph